# Error in using static function in struct in namespace. (c++)

Tags: c++, oop, static, namespaces

I have this code there I create the struct with static function in the namespace:

```
namespace Hashing {
    ///...
    struct Hash {
        ///...
        static void init(int n, const ull m = 31ull) {
             ///...
        }
    };
    ///...
}
```

I use the following code in main:

```
int main() {
    ///...
    Hashing::Hash.init(12);
    ///...
}
```

The error occurred:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token
  Hashing::Hash.init(12);
               ^
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to: `Hashing::Hash::init(12);`. Static member functions are not associated with any object.

Comment: Oooo. How could I not notice it?

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин you'd be surprised what you can miss. I couldn't find a flashlight for three weeks because someone had moved it from the top of the microwave to beside the microwave, at most a foot away.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods are called with `::` such as `Hash::init()`.

Using the `.` is for member functions and variables. the class `Hash` is not a member, but a `Hash h` would be.

Answer (score 0):

The `.` should be `::`.

Edited code:

```
#include <iostream>
namespace Hashing{
  struct Hash{
    static void print(int num){
      std::cout<<num<<"\n";
    }
  };
}
int main() {
  Hashing::Hash::print(12);
}
```